# Selectize.js: onItemAdd event triggered when silently adding an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Using Selectize.js, I'm trying to initialize the dynamically pre-select one of the item of the list without triggering the `onItemAdd` event. In the following code, the event is triggered even if the `silent` parameter is truthy:

```
$(function () {
    $('select').selectize({
        onItemAdd: function () {
            alert("Add item");
        }
    });
    // this triggers an the event
    $('select')[0].selectize.addItem('2', true);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuzat0dc/1/

According to the documentation:

- `addItem(value, silent)`: "Selects" an item. Adds it to the list at the current caret position. If "silent" is truthy, no change event will be fired on the original input.

Any idea how to avoid triggering the `onItemAdd` event? Is the `silent` parameter b0rked or should I use the `change` event instead?

Comment: Note: I could use the `off(...)` and `on(...)` functions to disable the handler, add the item then re-enable to handler, but that doesn't look like the way it should be done =/

Comment: What do you run .off() and .on()? The original select?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was the `.on()` and `.off()` event methods of the [selectize instance](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_events)

Answer (score 7):

A quick fix that worked for me was to keep a state flag and refer to it in the event handler...

```
$(function () {

  var initialising = true;

  $('select').selectize({
    onItemAdd: function () {
      if(!initialising) { 
        alert("Add item");
      }
    }
  });

  // this triggers an the event
  $('select')[0].selectize.addItem('2', true);

  initialising = false;
});
```

Comment: Yeah that's an "acceptable" solution although it is kind of _hacky_... :-p

Answer (score 2):

The silent parameter in `addItem(value, silent)` affects only to the fact whether or not the `change` event. You can't avoid `item_add` event with `silent = true`.

Comment: And so, there is no way to avoid the `item_add` event to be fired other than using `off(...)` before and `on(...)` after manually adding the item?

Comment: Actually this is not true, the `change` event is fired anyway. The JSFiddle linked in the initial question has been updated to show this.

Comment: It's a bug in 0.12.0 version. Try this sample http://jsfiddle.net/6zyums3d/1/ with 0.12.1 version.

Comment: @alemv  I'm still seeing this issue in 0.12.6 and 0.12.4, actually. setValue() fires onItemAdd even though my understanding is it should not when "silent". I fixed my problem by changing my event binding FROM "onItemAdd: selectionChange(...)" TO "onChange: selectionChange(...)"

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was to store `item_add` event locally, remove it from selectize instance and set it back after I added the item:

```
onItemAdd: function(val) {
  var e = this._events['item_add'];
  delete this._events['item_add'];
  this.addItem(123);
  this._events['item_add'] = e;
}
```